# Are vir and fémina counterparts of each other?

Tags: noun, gender

pater means father, and mater means mother, and the two words have similar forms.

vir means "man; husband", and fémina means  "woman; wife". But the two words look very different from each other. I was wondering if there is a word that looks similar to vir or femina, and means "woman, wife" or "man, husband"?

Comment: As far as I know, usual words for "husband" and "wife" are "maritus" and "uxor", respectively.

Comment: Well, there's *virgo*, though it definitely doesn't mean "wife" ...

Answer (score 4):

*Pater* and *māter* have the same ending due to an analogy back in Proto-Indo-European, but most kinship terms in Latin don't have that same similarity. For example, *frāter* "brother" and *soror* "sister" don't look much alike.

The ones that *do* look similar can usually be analyzed as a single word that can take different gender markings, like *fīlius* "son" and *fīlia* "daughter". Only the ending changes to indicate the gender, just like with an adjective: a good son is a *fīlius bonus* and a good daughter is a *fīlia bona*.

EDIT: And as far as I know, there are no general terms for "husband" and "wife", or "man" and "woman", that work like this. There's *marītus* and *marīta*, literally an adjective "married", if that suits your purposes, but it's a less common way to refer to a person, married or not.

Answer (score 2):

Many languages use words of unrelated origins to refer to coordinate concepts like "man" and "woman", "king" and "queen", "boy" and "girl" etc. So the fact that *vir* and *fēmina* "look very different from each other" should not be seen as unusual or in need of explanation.

The word *fēmina* is generally considered to be derived from a root that referred to the concept of nursing (also the source of the verb *fēl(l)ō* "to suck"). Since the root itself refers to a female-associated activity, it isn't likely for a word meaning "man" to be derived from it. (Note that *fēmina* does not specifically refer to an adult human, but also is the general Latin word for 'female' in reference to non-human animals or even plants. The more specific Latin word for a female adult human is *mulier*. I posted a Q&A [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/19476/) about the difference).

The word *vir* appears to have been associated with masculinity from early on, judging from the cognates in other Indo-European languages, but some scholars apparently think it originally had the sense of 'young, youth', per [F.J. Ledo-Lemos's answer to *Are "vir" and "virgo" etymologically related?*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/5735/9) Some grammarians allege that a word *[vira](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/vira)* was formerly used with the sense 'woman', but it's not clear how accurate this is. Cairnarvon linked to the two places this form appears in the PHI Latin Texts corpus: Festus's *De verborum significatu* ("Sed feminas antiqui [...] viras appellabant; unde adhuc permanent virgines et viragines") and Servius's commentary on the Aeneid ("has antiqui viras dicebant"), and it also appears in Isidore, who probably took it from a prior grammatical work ("quae nunc *femina,* antiquitus *vira* vocabatur; sicut a *servo serva,* sicut a *famulo famula,* ita a *viro vira*"). There is also the word *[virāgō](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/virago)* but this does not refer to a wife, but specifically to a manlike or manly woman.

The word *[coniu(n)x](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/coniunx),* like English "consort", can refer to a wife or (more rarely) a husband.

Comment: Isidore's source in this case is likely Festus, who is fractionally more credible, but all the same *vira* looks to be [a grammarian concoction](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23viras%23).

Comment: @Cairnarvon: thank you for the pointer! I was just working my way though the reference in De Vaan but didn't think to simply do a PHI search, haha.